# Checking if a raster is unprojected

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

My script should stop if the file I read is unprojected.
What is the easiest way to do it with gdal Python binding ?

**PS:**

I know (I will post it as an answer) how to do it using `rasterio` but it's an open-source project based on `gdal` so I [can't use it](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html#mutual-incompatibilities).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much same approach with GDAL.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
src=gdal.Open('4326.tif')
crs=src.GetSpatialRef()
crs.IsProjected()
```

Comment: I have an image in lat/long (EPSG:4326) and the results is (97.34316587320873, 0.008983152841195215, 0.0, 20.465555255178487, 0.0, -0.008983152841195217) even though it's unprojected. Maybe it's unclear but what I look for is not "missing crs" but "unprojected" one.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of "ungeoreferenced".

Comment: Now answered to what you were really asking.

Answer (score 2):

For user that (unlike me in this situation) can use `rasterio` lib to perform this task, you need to check if the projection set in the file is unprojected:

```py
import rasterio as rio 

with rio.open("file.tif") as f: 
    crs = f.meta["crs"]
    print(crs.is_projected)
```

For more information refer to [pyproj `CRS` documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#pyproj.crs.CRS.is_projected).